# Как вставить нестандартный символ (к примеру, эмодзи) в Python-строку?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

Хотелось бы описание способа вставки как по Unicode-коду, так и по ASCII.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707222/print-python-emoji-as-unicode-string

Comment: Копируешь имодзю и вставляешь.